# Merging commits from the same user appearing twice on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Noticed my name appears twice on my repository,on GitHub updates you see my GitHub profile and only my commits on the website which is editing readme. On the other name(which still is mine) you see my git updates from the computer.

How can i merge the two since they all belong to me. Here is a sample. So far my code contributions are not visible on the contribution page. Here is the link,
how can i fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those commits are not linked to your GitHub user.

From the official **[GitHub help article](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)**:

> If your commits are not linked to any user, we will display the grey Octocat logo beside them.
>
> To check the email address used for those commits and connect commits to your account, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Navigate to the commit by clicking the commit message link.
> 2. To read a message about why the commit is not linked, hover over the blue to the right of the username:
>
> [image]
>
> **Unrecognized author (with email address):** If you see this message with an email address, it means the address has not been added to your account settings. To link your commits, [add the email address to your GitHub email settings](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account).
>
> **Unrecognized author (no email address)**: If you see this message without an email address, it means you used a generic email address that can't be added to your email settings. You will need to [set your commit email address in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git), then [add the new address to your GitHub email settings](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account) to link your future commits. Old commits will not be linked.
>
> **Invalid email**: This means the email address in your local Git configuration settings is either blank or not formatted as an email address. You will need to [set your commit email address in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git), then [add the new address to your GitHub email settings](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account) to link your future commits. Old commits will not be linked.

If there is comment, you can try associating your commits with your GitHub username using `git config --global user.email "your_email@gmail.com"`. The email address **must** be the same for Git and GitHub. Also note that this will only work for **future** commits. For past commits, you can re-commit if needed with:

```
git reset --soft HEAD
git config --global user.email "your_email@gmail.com"
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

Also, please actually [**require** your admins to approve Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/), (rather than just suggesting that the public don't push to your `master` branch without doing so). By leaving Pull Requests open to be merged by the public, you're opening yourself to all sorts of malpractice.

Comment: But it says authored by me, which means it does recognize it is me? i don't see that unrecognized author because it displays my name.

Comment: It displays the name you set locally. You just so happen to be using (almost) identical names for both your local Git settings and your remote GitHub name. The difference is in the casing. GitHub still doesn't recognise you, so falls back to the name that was sent out with the commit :)

Comment: So what do i do ? my email is set on my GitHub account. This is bases on the fact that i have no suggestions as you display on your answer.

Comment: Well you can try associating your commits with your GitHub username using `git config --global user.email "your_email@gmail.com"`. Note that it only will work for **future** commits though. And the two emails do indeed need to be the same :)

Comment: Thanks, i think the answer should be the one you just posted :) on the comments now.

Comment: Cool; I'll update my answer to cover that as well :)

Comment: Thanks you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Some commits using my personal email, other commits using my business email. Just go to [Email Settings on GitHub](https://github.com/settings/emails) and add your emails.